# Is there a better font choice for this invite?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, critique

I'm making my company's holiday party invite (to be sent via email). I thought it was looking pretty good until I added the actual detail information (what, when where and everything below that).

I used Swis72 Lt BT and Swis72 Lt for that section.

I can't put my finger on exactly why I think it doesn't look good anymore but I suspect it has to do with my font choice. I have tried placing other fonts in that are fairly straight, sans-serif and light but none of them seem to fit.

I also know that it's ideal to limit the number of fonts, so I was trying to keep this invite down to two fonts with different weights and styles.

Can anyone recommend a better font choice to make this invite more appealing?

[image: The email invite]

Comment: it's all to tight, make the font a px or two smaller, and open up the leading/line-height. it'll be easier to read.

Comment: @BrianC thanks! I lowered the font size and increased the leading and I think it looks much better now. I'm still wondering if there's a better font choice for me, but if I'm going to stick with this one smaller font with more space is definitely the way to go. :)

Comment: Swiss is a nice font, but a bit on the plain side for an invitation. If you prefer a san serif font, you could try one that has a bit more embellishment. Otherwise, you could emphasizing  font weights, like making the When, What, Where bolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a different san serif font that doesn't resemble Arial as much. 
A few suggestions (and personal favorites) are **Gotham**, **Montserrat**, and **Proxima Nova**.

[image: Gotham Font Styles]

[image: Montserrat Font Styles]

[image: Proxima Nova Font Styles]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those are all really gorgeous sans serif fonts. I've definitely used them before, but seeing them laid out like this makes it so much easier to compare and choose. Thanks very much! :)